# Подходящий хостинг

Tags: хостинг

Добрый день. Дописываю сайт. Хочу на выходных купить для него хостинг. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Изначально решил посмотреть самостоятельно, наткнулся на топ хостеров РФ, посмотрел по отзывам, выбрал. Зарегистрировавшись был приятно удивлен тем, что у них 10 тестовых дней, после которых нужно сделать оплату и отзывчивая служба поддержки. Но после этого, благо до оплаты, наткнулся на статью, на хабре об этом хостере. Узнал что у них проблемы с работой htaccess фалов, т.к. там смесь апача и nginx. А так-же уж очень часто сайты на их хостингах становятся недоступны на 5-10 минут. В связи с этим прошу вас посоветовать, может вы пользовались или пользуетесь в данный момент услугами качественного хостера, у кого стоит покупать данную услугу.

Мне нужно примерно следующее:

- Полная поддержка htaccess
- Php версии 7+
- Почта, чтобы можно было сделать адрес admin@домен.ру, для фидбека
- Стабильная работа без сбоев
- 5-10 гб, для начала

Спасибо)

Comment: Пользовался долго хостингом [Джино](https://hosting.jino.ru/), всё что вам надо там есть, удобно что платить нужно только за то что действительно надо, и перебоев не было, за год было 2-3 перебоя, но всё возмещали. Пользовался больше года, ушел от них пару месяцев назад в связи с арендой VPS, но не думаю что что-то изменилось.

Comment: https://sweb.ru/hosting/

Comment: Любой VDS, например

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/

Comment: http://wmz-host.ru/ я использовал этот. Админка простая, гибкие настройки. Настроил минут за 15, быстро обновился домен